# Python - Linked list issue

Tags: python, linked-list, issue-tracking

I am trying to do a leetcode and test it on my computer, but I get an error saying that he can't find the curr.next which is written in the class above.

```
class ListNode():
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
class Solution(ListNode):
    def reverseList(self, head):
     # Two pointer solution itertaively where T O(n) and M O(1)
        val = 0
        next = None
        prev, curr = None, head
        while curr:
            temp = curr.next  <--- here is the error
            curr.next = prev
            prev = curr
            curr = temp
        return prev

head = Solution()
head.reverseList([1,3,3,4,5,5,6])
```

could you please help me I know im doing something wrong but can't find the issue. (im a newbie) :)

Comment: The issue is that you provide a list rather than a ListNode as parameter when you call `reverseList`. Since a list didn't have a `next` property your program have this error. You should try to create the same list using `ListNode` and see if it's better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you need to create ListNode object not just a normal list as you do :

```py
class ListNode():
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
class Solution(ListNode):
    def reverseList(self, head):
     # Two pointer solution itertaively where T O(n) and M O(1)
        val = 0
        next = None
        prev, curr = None, head
        while curr:
            temp = curr.next  <--- here is the error
            curr.next = prev
            prev = curr
            curr = temp
        return prev

head = Solution()
node7 = ListNode(val=6)
node6 = ListNode(val=5, next=node7)
node5 = ListNode(val=5, next=node6)
node4 = ListNode(val=4, next=node5)
node3 = ListNode(val=3, next=node4)
node2 = ListNode(val=3, next=node3)
node1 = ListNode(val=1, next=node2)
head.reverseList(node1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! this was what I was missing! (Y) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A function can be created to make a linked list from a list in a similar fashion. But here's a rough implementation of the same!

```
class ListNode():
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

class Solution(ListNode):
    def reverseList(self, head):
     # Two pointer solution itertaively where T O(n) and M O(1)
        val = 0
        next = None
        prev, curr = None, head
        while curr:
            temp = curr.next
            curr.next = prev
            prev = curr
            curr = temp
        return prev

    def printLinkedList(self, head):
        temp = head
        while(temp):
            print(temp.val)
            temp = temp.next

# create linked list
head = ListNode(1)
head.next = ListNode(2)
head.next.next = ListNode(3)
head.next.next.next = ListNode(4)
head.next.next.next.next = ListNode(5)
head.next.next.next.next.next = ListNode(6)

# reverse and print
s = Solution()
new_head = s.reverseList(head)
s.printLinkedList(new_head)
```